# Add days to Linq - Hard to indicate the correct number of days

Tags: sql, linq

I need to build up such that my LINQ add four days into tablen. the idea behind it must be that it should add 4 days ahead.

My old sql so here out

```
UPDATE brugere SET rank = 6, trydato = DateAdd(Day,4,GetDate()) WHERE Id = 1;
```

my new way looks like this,

```
protected void ButtonTryRank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int brugerid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);

    var UserRank = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(UsersRank => UsersRank.Id == brugerid);
    if (UserRank != null)
    {
        UserRank.rank = 6;

        //its error are here
        UserRank.trydato = DateTime.Today.AddDays(4).Date;

        //save the users info
        db.SubmitChanges();

        Response.Redirect("wall.aspx?rank-opdater=true");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("wall.aspx?rank-opdater=false&fejl=logoutNow");
    }

}
```

The problem underlying that it will not add the 4 days,

> 'wall.DateTime(string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have somewhere method called DateTime(string p), may be static or within your class. Try with full name:

```
UserRank.trydato = System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(4).Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !. I hope you will give me a +1 to a good question. and i have giv u +1 and link :D